# Array of custom object from .NET to VB6

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, com-interop

I've written a small library in C#.

In this library there are two classes that are `ComVisible`.

The first one has a method that provide a array of custom objects (declared in the second class).

I tested the library with a small c# application and everything work.
Then I do the same thing VB6. The problem occurs when I call the method I descibed before. I get a Type Mismatch error.

Here's the BV6 code:

```
   Private Sub Command1_Click()
       Dim Flussi As FMDriver.FMDriver  
       Set Flussi = New FMDriver.FMDriver
       [...]
       Dim temp() As FMDriver.FM
       temp = Flussi.GetElabData(station, codpar, data, tabella, nfunz, tiponfunz)
       [...]
```

This is the custom class `FM`

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class FM
{
    public FM() { }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public double Value { get; set; }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public double IDisp { get; set; } 
}
```

Any idea? If from the response I extract only one element it works.

EDIT:

Another strange thing...

```
Dim pippo As FM
Set pippo = CreateObject("fmdriver.fm")
pippo.Value = 100
pippo.IDisp = 43    
pippo = Flussi.GetElabData( [..cut..] )(4)
```

In `Pippo.Value` there's the correct value that `GetElabData` return on the 4th position of the array but in `Pippo.IDisp` the value doesn't change, it remains `43`instead of getting the new value.

Comment: this is a complete sample that shows how to solve your problem [`http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12300/An-ASP-NET-Application-Using-a-MySQL-Database`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12300/An-ASP-NET-Application-Using-a-MySQL-Database) i hope it could help you

Comment: If you did `Dim temp() As Object` or `Dim temp As Variant`, would that get around the Type Mismatch?

Comment: Hassan Wasef, maybe you post on the wrong question? :)

Rskar, if I use Object or Variant I get the same error. :(

Comment: Whats the definition and code behind `FMDriver.GetElabData()`?

Comment: `[ComVisible(true)]
public FM[] GetFMData( [...cut...] )
{     
    List<FM> _Result = new List<FM>(); 
    // [... bla bla bla ...]
    return _Result.ToArray<FM>()
}`

Comment: Can you post the IDL from the typelib that was generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created all my beautifull methods that returns custom obj (for .NET apps) and a couple of methods, dedicated to VB6, with the `[ComVisible(true)]` tag, that returns more siple arrays of values (part of the result of the other methods).
So I think that returning custom Obj to VB6 it's not very reliable and sometimes it doesn't work at all.